# How do I get test cases results from Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-platform, cloud, firebase-test-lab

I have setup a Google Cloud function that reports Firebase Test Lab results to Slack with the help of some [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/test-lab-events)

However, it currently only displays "PASSED" or "FAILED" which isn't that helpful. I want to display the total amount of tests passed e.g. `9/20 test cases passed`.

I can't find any documentation detailing how to do this. Is it not possible?

This is my current function:

```
exports.postTestResultsToSlack = functions.testLab
  .testMatrix()
  .onComplete(async testMatrix => {

    if (testMatrix.clientInfo.details['testType'] != 'regression') {
      // Not regression tests
      return null;
    }

    const { testMatrixId, state, outcomeSummary, resultStorage } = testMatrix;

    const colour = getSlackColour(outcomeSummary)

    const title = `*Test Session: ${testMatrixId}*`;

    const details = `7/10 passed (58%)`;  // Replace hardcoded data here

    const resultURL = resultStorage.resultsUrl

    const slackResponse = await postToSlack(colour, title, details, resultURL);

    functions.logger.log(JSON.stringify(slackResponse.data));
  });
```

Below is a screenshot of the data I want but can't find out how to get:
[image: Results]

Comment: Hey, so the screenshot you have provided is what you want to retrieve from test lab as an output of Cloud Functions, is that what you want to do?

Comment: @ZeenathSN Yes, the CI systems run automated tests, when complete it triggers the cloud function, so I want to send the data to Slack from Cloud Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way through the Functions SDK to get this data. You will need to make a HTTPs call to the respective API endpoint to retrieve this.

I don't have the JavaScript code at hand, but e.g. here's the `curl`/`gcloud` command to call this endpoint that has this data:

```sh
curl \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "X-Goog-User-Project: <projectid>" \
https://toolresults.googleapis.com/toolresults/v1beta3/projects/<projectid>/histories/<historyid>/executions/<executionid>/environments
```

The `historyid` and `executionid` for this test are stored in `TestMatrix.resultStorage`. Don't overlook that you have to provide the `projectid` in 2 places.

The result will be a JSON containing a list of `Environment`s. The data you want is in the `Environment.environmentResult.testSuiteOverviews` field.

Comment: Hi, is this still the case until today or there are now APIs added to the Test Lab Function SDK? Thanks